# QFT for mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, knot-theory, online-resources, quantum-field-theory

I have a graduate degree in mathematics, I want to learn enough QFT to understand whats going on in Wittens paper about QFT and the Jones polynomial. So I need some QFT and maybe Chern-Simons theory. What are good resources to learn whats necessary? I want to understand fully this paper.

Comment: A link to the paper you mentioned would be great. Though I think this question is more appropriate for Physics.SE

Comment: Im not interested in physics

Comment: You just said you want to learn QFT. If you mean quantum field theory, then you will have better luck asking this question on Physics.SE. Even if you only want to learn the mathematical language of the theory, physicists are still better equipped to answer that. In fact, why didn't you just [google it](https://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZSYrV_XrPMT07gT314z4Bw&gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=quantum+field+theory+for+mathematicians) in the first place?

Comment: @YuriyS Why would physicists be better equipped to answer that? QFT is now also a mathematical discipline in its own right (albeit one I am not qualified to say anythng about).

Comment: @MikeMiller, I did not know that. If it's true, I will delete my comments. Although my google link still works

Comment: And here is a question from Phys.SE about the same thing: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27700/quantum-field-theory-from-a-mathematical-point-of-view with a lot of answers. So my point stands

Comment: I am not an expert but, QFT could be approached via path-integrals, or via canonical quantization (the first is the Lagrangian approach, while the other is the Hamiltonian approach, so to speak). My impression is that Witten loves the path-integral approach. I would start by understanding path-integrals (I personally love Feynman-Hibbs for that, although it is only path-integrals for quantum mechanics, but then you can generalize). After that, you can maybe try the book by Lewis Ryder say, on QFT, though there are many other choices, but this one seems like a lighter introduction to QFT.

Comment: Regarding Chern-Simons theory, what about the paper by Chern and Simons as a start? At least it would explain the origin of the ideas, as secondary characteristic classes. I remember reading some nice paper, very well written, by Daniel Freed on Chern-Simons theory. You may want to check out some of his expository papers on the subject.

Comment: Finally, I would like to say that Physics and Mathematics are both linked together, in many different ways. And to understand someone like Witten, you need to have a good understanding of both!

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good resource might (just might) be the following book:

Quantum Fields and Strings a Course for Mathematicians. This book emphasizes mathematical rigor and technique. I haven't gone through all of it, but it might have what you're looking for.